# 'Update' command does not work in VisualSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I am using TortoiseSVN/Subversion/VisualSVN to manage version control solely - I am the only developer. Being new I created the Trunk and a Branch with the branch to use as a WIP and the Trunk to make urgent bug fixes and issue releases blah blah blah ...

Now I have done my first bug fix and released it and now need to bring the few changes made in the trunk (committed) into my WIP (committed) version. The documentation for VisualSVN indicates that I need to do an Update .. to quote ..

> "It often happens that while you've been working on your changes,
>   somebody else already finished and committed their own changes to the
>   repository. Thus it's a good idea to merge any changes into your
>   working copy before commiting. Just choose **VisualSVN | Update** main
>   menu command and all changes committed by others but not reflected in
>   your working copy will be incorporated into your working copy."

Clicking the Update appears to do nothing. The few changes made in my Trunk are not imported into my WIP copy.

Is this a bug or am I completely misunderstanding how it's all supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are reading about and what you want to do is not the same thing. As Damien points out Update is used to update your copy (be it branch or trunk) to get other peoples changes into it.

What you want to do if I read it correctly is to merge the trunk into your branch and it's something you can read about how to do here http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html just scroll down to **Keeping a Branch in Sync**

Answer (score 1):

An Update command downloads the latest version from the repository that may have been updated by other developers, and it either updates your version or merges it with your changes. 
As you're the only developer, you won't be using this much.

Use the Commit command to save your changes.

Comment: Thanks ... this dawned on me about an hour after posting :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you have two branches - "trunk" and "branch" then you won't see changes made in one branch in the other branch unless and until you merge from one to the other.